# Override a components template in Angular2/4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

If I detail the problem I'm trying to solve, it will help with my question.

I want to use HTML in the Angular Material tooltip, the current template doesn't enable this functionality:

```
<div class="mat-tooltip"
     [ngClass]="tooltipClass"
     [style.transform-origin]="_transformOrigin"
     [@state]="_visibility"
     (@state.done)="_afterVisibilityAnimation($event)">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

In order to use HTML in the tooltip I'd like to override the template to the following:

```
<div class="mat-tooltip"
     [ngClass]="tooltipClass"
     [innerHTML]="message"
     [style.transform-origin]="_transformOrigin"
     [@state]="_visibility"
     (@state.done)="_afterVisibilityAnimation($event)">
</div>
```

Is this possible? Is there another method I'm overlooking to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html file cannot be changed, however you can access the element from the component.ts file

```
@ViewChild('dataContainer') dataContainer: ElementRef;

loadData(data) {
    this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = data;
}
```

as found in thie [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38826472/7564182).